# Count attributes in child model through has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:

`user.rb`
attributes: `name`, `gender`

and

`participation.rb`
attributes: `user_id` + some other

A user `has_many :participations`
A participation `belongs_to :user`

I now simply want to find out how many males do I have for a participation collection:

```
@participations = Participation.all
@males = @participations.joins(:user).where(gender: 'male').count
```

I understood it this way that I have to join the user model through participations like in the above snippet but that does not work.

Another way would be to simply write:

```
@males = @participations.users.where(gender: 'male').count
```

I think I misunderstood something essential here.
How can I solve my problem "the rails way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify table name in your query, like this:

```
@males = @participations.joins(:user).where(users: {gender: 'male'})
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use eager loading with `:includes`:

```
@males = @participations.includes(:user).where(users: {gender: 'male'})
```

Comment: Why should it take less time?

Comment: Sorry I mean about eager loading stuffs.

Comment: Ok, so you should probably edit your answer since it's unlikely to take less time.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a males scope on the user, and then define a new association "males" or "male_users" on participants into which you merge that scope, to allow you to:

```
@participations.male_users.count
```